# google asssitant: what is the temperature inside? does not hit the endpoint

Tags: actions-on-google

One of the requirement of Google Assistant with thermostat test is

`What is the temperature inside? (with the A/C on)   QUERY   interrogative
What is the temperature inside? (with the A/C off)  QUERY   interrogative`

The query used to work, but not recently.

`what is the temperature inside?
Sorry, I’m not sure which device you’d like to control.`

Query for one thermostat still work

`What is the temperature of main ac one?
It's currently 81 degrees.`

Is there any change in the query, or that is the bug of Google Assistant for smart home?

Thanks.

Comment: How many temperature setting devices are in your home graph? It seems like you have several, and disambiguation is required.

Comment: I have 10 ACs (action.devices.types.AC_UNIT) in this account. Could you please be more verbose in "disambiguation is required"?

Comment: Okay, then that makes sense. If you say "what is the temperature inside", it is going to look for a device that can provide this result. If you have ten, the Google Assistant will not know which one you want to query. The device is ambiguous, so there is a follow-up question automatically to disambiguate the device.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was thought that this command would summarize all thermostats in one home.